# How to reference context from entity class?

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Im attempting to add some business logic to the generated LINQ to Entity entity classes generated when I imported my SQL Server DB model using the VS 2010 wizard.

I am doing this by adding partial classes. So far so good. However I would like the settting of a member of my new partial to check and get some values from another table/entity from the same context.

Should I use a LINQ query to do this? If so how would I reference the parent context?

Or should I add some kind of navigation property to provide the same functionality? If so where could I find *VB* instruction on this (sorry, idk enough to work from C# instruction).

An example of what I would like to be able to do is (If I used a query); inside a property Set, confirm presence of the ID and get data from the Name field of *a different table/entity within the same context* to populate some class members.

```
Public Partial Class MyTable
    Private assignedName As String
    Private assignedId As Integer

    Public WriteOnly  Property AcId As Integer
        Set (value As Integer)
            Dim NameString = From q In myDataContext.AnotherTable
                             Where q.Id = value And q.Ac = True
                             Select q.Name
            If NameString IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.assignedName = NameString
                Me.assignedId = value
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Thanks

Comment: I really think that your classes should know nothing about context. This is business logic, so I would let that in the "business layer", whichever way you call it.

Comment: Yes, this is how I started out originally, but doing this I would then require two classes to represent the data associated with a single thing, in this case the records on the table.... I though it better to have all in the one class...